# Why MySQL returns different result for calculation?

Tags: mysql

I've been very confused because this calculation gives different results.

[Method 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RBOq.png)

```
select 6000000*(95/365)*(3.00/100) = 46849.3149600000. Refer above image in link
```

[Method 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVfVM.png)

```
select ((6000000*95*3.00)/36500) = 46849.315068. Refer above image in link
```

When calculate using calculator getting same results for above two methods

46849.315068

Can someone explain me this weird behaviour?

**Note** I'm using Mysql aurora AWS.

Comment: Your first calculation has many more operations than your second. Floating point arithmetic is subject to rounding errors on a computer. Your results are accurate to six 10,000ths. I'd say that's pretty good. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/14853083)

Comment: NB The result of your second calculation as typed is not `46849.315068` but `16438358.775342465753424657534247`.

Comment: [tag:sql-query-store] has nothing to do with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in results between Method 1 and Method 2 is due to the way floating-point arithmetic is performed in MySQL and other programming languages.

Method 1: `select 6000000*(95/365)*(3.00/100)`

In this method, the division operations `(95/365)` and `(3.00/100)` are performed first, resulting in decimal approximations. Then the multiplication operations are performed. The intermediate results are rounded to a certain number of decimal places, which can lead to slight differences in the final result.

Method 2: `select ((6000000*95*3.00)/36500)`

In this method, the multiplication operations `(6000000*95*3.00)` are performed first. Since multiplication is generally more accurate than division in floating-point arithmetic, the intermediate result retains more precision. Then the division operation `(result)/36500` is performed, which can also introduce a small rounding error.

The differences in precision and rounding can cause the two methods to produce slightly different results, even though they represent the same mathematical calculation.